# Bash Script doesn't print out as expected. What is wrong with my script?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a BASH script that reads arguments, testing if they are a directory, ordinary, executable, or symbolic link files and print them out in the terminal.

When executing my script i use "./myscript.bash *" to see but i dont get any predicted results. I do get the names of all items in my home directory being "not found" only. Example:

"Desktop not found"
"Downloads not found"
etc
EVEN though they are there, in my home folder, and are directories. Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $*; do
    if [ -d “{$i}” ]; then
        echo “${i} (Directory)”;
    elif [ -x “{$i}” ]; then
        echo “${i} (Executable)”;
    elif [ -h “{$i}” ]; then
        echo “${i} (Symbolic)”;
    elif [ -f “{$i}” ]; then
        echo “${i} (Ordinary)”;
    else
        echo “${i} not found”
    fi

done
```

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thanks the `$i` helped it work. But why `"$@"` instead of `$*`?

Answer (score 1):

First rule of debugging simple scripts:

> If it doesn't work, try echoing.

In this case:

```
for i in $*; do
    echo  "testing if “{$i}” exists"
    if [ -d “{$i}” ]; then
        echo “${i} (Directory)”;
<... rest of the script ...>
```

You will immediately see that the reply is:

```
testing if “{Downloads}” exists
...
```

That is: the test is if ”{Downloads}” (smartquotes-accolade open-Downloads-accolade close smartquotes) exists.

That directory will probably not exist.

The smartquotes may be an oversight for a beginning shell-scripter.  Bash (and most other shells as well) are very picky in the use of quotes. A single quote (`'`) has a different meaning from a double-quote (`"`). Back-quotes  mean something different as well. Smartquotes are the ones that mother gave you, don't do anything at all (if you forgive my Jefferson Airplane reference). You definitely want the double quotes (`"`) here, because they allow variable expansion.

Next are the `{` and `}`.In your `echo`'s, you give:

```
echo “${i} not found”
```

but in the `if` it is `{$i}`. Spot the difference. If you used

```
if [ -d "${i}" ]; then
```

it would have worked.

Kamil wrote in his comments:

> You hardly ever want `$*`; you almost always want `"$@"` instead.

and he is right. There are complete pages devoted to the difference of `$*`and `"$@"`, but the simplest way to show the difference is with:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ------------------
echo '$*'
for i in $* ; do echo $i ; done
echo ------------------
echo '"$@"'
for i in "$@" ; do echo $i ; done
echo ------------------
```

(I called this script `a`) and execute with:

```
bash a 'plop 123' plop 123
------------------
$*
plop
123
plop
123
------------------
"$@"
plop 123
plop
123
------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

@ljm hit the nail on the head, the only thing i would say to expand on that is always echo for the result desired and build better functionality around that.

In short, first make sure it works, then make it work better

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).